# preg_match get the id from url

Tags: php

Not quite understanding this. I am looking to get the id from url. path looks something like `site.com/shop/product/view?id=1&name=name`. Im also confused what `matches` mean. I read the documentation and some sites, I still don't get it. So like for mine $matches[0] does that mean the first character after the match. Saw some examples and it didn't look like it.

```
public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo){
    if (preg_match('/id=[0-9]*/', $pathInfo, $matches))
            $id = $matches[0];
```

tried `if (preg_match('/^shop/product/view?id=(\d+)', $pathInfo, $matches))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When invoking the default usage of [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) (i.e. without the [`PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-parameters) flag), the `$matches` array will hold the completely matched pattern in `$matches[0]` and optionally matched subpatterns in subsequent indices.

A subpattern is one that is defined in parentheses. Consider this example pattern:

`/^\d+(\.\d+)$/`

<sup>(it tries to match a decimal number, and capture the decimal point and following digits in the subpattern)</sup>

The first (and only) subpattern in this example is `(\.\d+)`. Invoked against the following string:

`10.54`

... the complete match `10.54` will be in `$matches[0]`, whereas the subpattern match `.54` will be in `$matches[1]`.

In your last example, you were actually on the right track! The value of `id`, you were going for, would actually be captured in `$matched[1]` already, if it weren't for a few important details:

1. Patterns [need to be enclosed in delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). In your case you were going for slashes, but forgot to close the pattern with the same delimiter. However, since you are trying to *match* slashes as well, you either need to escape the slashes inside the pattern (with a backslash) *or* use another delimiter (`~` for instance).
2. The actual string in `$pathInfo` probably starts with a slash and, since the beginning of your pattern is defined as `/^shop ...` (meaning: begin pattern (`/`); start matching at the start of the string (`^`); find `shop` at the start of the string), it won't match your input.

So, rounding it all up; if you adjust your pattern to:

`~^/shop/product/view?id=(\d+)~`

... then `$matches[1]` will hold the `id` value you're looking for (provided my assumptions are correct, and the URL is consistently formed).

Having said all this however, [Ghost's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25101442/165154) is probably not a bad idea. Because what happens when the `id` is actually in another place in the actual URL, etc.? There's numerous ways to catch this with regular expressions too of course, but Ghost's suggestion is probably just as, if not more, reliable.

Comment: Thank you all for all the alternatives! But this was a clear answer to my question as to what matches means.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation that will leave you with the query string in an associative array. Keep in mind most http servers have a cgi variable available as  `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

```
$url = 'site.com/shop/product/view?id=1&name=name';
$url = explode('/', $url);

$last = $url[count($url)-1];

$position = 0;
$query = '';

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($last); $i++) {
  if($last[$i] === '?') {
    $query = substr($last, $i + 1);
    break;
  }
}

$parts = explode('&', $query);
$final = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
  $data = explode('=', $parts[$i]);
  $final[$data[0]] = $data[1];

}


var_dump($final);
```

Program Output

```
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "name"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with your code, you can do the it like this too, using the explode function

```
$url = "site.com/shop/product/view?id=1231&name=name";
if (preg_match('/id=[0-9]*/', $url, $matches))
    $id = $matches[0];

$req_id = explode('=', $id);
echo $req_id[1];
```